# Cannot retrieve the latest update value from database after running the ORM Lite UpdateBuilder.update() in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, orm, ormlite

I have trouble when updating the data in android by using ORM Lite because my updated data is not affected in database immediately. 
After the update process, I query the data from the database but I got the old data that was the same as before I update.

So, I solved this problem by refreshing each updated object by using refresh(Object) after the update process, the problem was OK(I can access the latest updated data from data in next query).

But I am not sure is it the best way or not? If there have another ways to 
solve this problem, could you please tell me?
Thanks.

Run the batch update by using UpdateBuilder.

```
try {
    Set<String> ids = accountIdSet;
    UpdateBuilder<Account, Long> updateBuilder = account.updateBuilder();
    updateBuilder.where().in(Account.ID,ids);
    updateBuilder.updateColumnValue(Account.REGISTERED, true);
    return updateBuilder.update();
} catch (SQLException e) { }
return 0;
```

After update process I do the query data from database by below lines.

```
try {
    Set<String> ids = accountIdSet;
    List<Account> result =  Account.queryBuilder().where().in(Account.ID, ids).query();
    if (result!=null) {
        for (Account acc : result) {
            Log.i(acc.getId() + ", registered = " + acc.getRegistered());
        }
        return result;
    }
} catch (SQLException e) { }
return null;
```

At that time I got the old value of data. For example -

```
1, registered = false
2, registered = false
3, registered = false
```

Result should be

```
1, registered = true
2, registered = true
3, registered = true
```

Comment: You certainly don't want the line `Account account = result.get(0);` but that doesn't explain the problem.

Comment: What does the update() method return?  Did it update rows?  Can you dump your database to see if it changed anything?  Can you turn on logging to validate that the update statement was doing the right thing?

Comment: update() method can return the correct value. For eg - if I update 1 row, it can return 1. But when I logging out the value after update process this value is also same with the old value(not the latest value). How can I see the data in sql lite database in android? Thanks.